# Rails Rake Task is not Saving in ActiveRecord/Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, task, rake

I've ran the function myself outside the rake and the record saves successfully just fine without errors.

```
namespace :scrape do
    task :site => [:environment] do
      session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
      session.get "/"
      puts 'exec scrape'
      logthis = Logger.new(STDOUT)
      puts logthis.info 
    end
end
```

I am calling a method in my controller. In my logger files. The method is being called based on the logger output.

```
I, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.073086 #4]  INFO -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-08 13:52:50 +0000
I, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.079545 #4]  INFO -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6] Processing by ApplicationController#scrape_reddit as HTML
D, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.238243 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6] ETHON: Libcurl initialized
D, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.243506 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6] ETHON: started MULTI
D, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.246125 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6] ETHON: performed MULTI
I, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.263252 #4]  INFO -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6]   Rendering scrape_reddit.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.431967 #4]  INFO -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6]   Rendered scrape_reddit.html.erb within layouts/application (168.1ms)
I, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.434184 #4]  INFO -- : [b54625f0-f000-46d5-91f9-fabb64da54a6] Completed 200 OK in 354ms (Views: 187.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
exec scrape
I, [2017-05-08T13:52:50.442605 #4]  INFO -- : nil
true
```

I have tried using `.save!` but that did not solve my problem.

I am running it in command line with `rake scrape:site`

This is with Postgres

Comment: Have you inspected the `logthis` object (without calling `.info`)? Also, try `stdout = session.get '/'` then `logthis = Logger.new(stdout)`.

Comment: Where did you try to call `save!` Where do you even create record? You question is unclear and seems to miss relevant code fragments.

Comment: The code I provided is only my rake file. As I have said before, I am calling a method in my controller. In this case, I made my index route to that method. I have already said that the method already works normally when I don't call it from rake. So when I visit, `localhost:3000/`the method is called and works as expected. I am trying to call the same method from rake.

Comment: @mmichaeI got this `#<Logger:0x007ff79907bde8 @level=0, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007ff79907bd98 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007ff79907bd48 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007ff79907bcf8>>>` I'm not sure what looks wrong in the log.